# LDAP config on Openfiler SAN

Tags: active-directory, linux-networking, ldap, windows-server-2022, openfiler

We have a production Openfiler SAN (vs 2.99) that has been using Windows Authentication to grab groups for file permissions for 5 or 6 years now (configured via the GUI). It's pointing to the then, PDC in the forest, a windows server 2008R2 box without any issues. We have upgraded to Windows server 2022 and moved the FSMO rules etc in order to decommission the 2008. We'd like to connect using LDAP, like we do with some of our other linux servers that pull using LDAP queries from the new Windows servers, . However, using the Openfiler GUI to try to get ldap queries working has proved fruitless.

Every time we try and submit changes, it takes 45mins + to re write all the permissions over the RAID 10 array, But it doesn't pull in any groups. We can successfully roll back to using AD authentication to the same Windows 2008R2 server. We can not talk to the new 2022 server using the FQDN and the same ReadOnly AD account user and password. Openfiler will only talk to the old 2008 box. It's seems like the GUI is not passing the information to the ldap.conf file? If that is what it is supposed to be using.

I say that because if we logon to Openfiler as root to the CLI and run this LDAP query

```
ldapsearch -x -W -H ldap://192.168.x.x -D "adman@ourcompany.com" -b "dc=ourcompany,dc=com"
```

We get all the expected return from our 2022 PDC. The Openfiler project seems to have gone dark and all hails have gone without reply. I'll try again tonight and with the LDAP change via the GUI initiated I'll see if the ldap.conf file has changed. I expect not, and still show the 'example' settings only.

The long of it is we are pushed for time to upgrade the Window domain, but will migrate the data to another platform. This is the last hold-out at the moment to moving forward with other urgent projects.

Thanks in advance for any advice.